# 3 columns data to be converted to date wise like in pivot tables

Tags: mysql

I have data like this.

```
br     date        total
602    20160901     22
603    20160901     23
602    20160902     24
603    20160902     25
```

I want out put like this.

```
br        date  
       20160901   20160902   tot
602     22         24          64
603     23         25          48
tot     45         49         102
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: You need 5 columns or rows?

Comment: Please mention clearly "What you expecting result?"

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).